# How to store property names and its values into dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to develop an API which will be taking few movie names as part of ViewModel and will be setting respective movie IDs in DTO.

The table representation for TBL_Movies (For example I have used only 5 data but in real there are quite few):

```
ID  MovieName
1   Indiana Jones
2   John Wick
3   James Bond
4   Wolverine


The table representation for TBL_Transact:

Tab_ID  MovieID1(int)   MovieID2(int)   MovieID3(int)   MovieID4(int)   
1   NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

The ViewModel structure:

```
{
    Tab_ID: int,
    MovieName1: "John Wick",
    MovieName2: "Wolverine",
    MovieName3: "Cast Away",
    MovieName4: "A-Team" // this doesn't exist in TBL_Movies and so it will return exception to the client
}
```

The above ViewModel will be passed to the API PUT endpoint and now I need to fetch the respective MovieIDs for respective ViewModel fields and store them in DTO.

The DTO (MovieDetailUpdateDto) structure:

```
{
    Tab_ID: int,
    MovieName1: string,
    MovieName2: string,
    MovieName3: string,
    MovieName4: string,
    MovieID1: int,
    MovieID2: int,
    MovieID3: int,
    MovieID4: int
}
```

So, DTO will be storing Movie ID in MovieID1 as the ID for the movie mentioned in the field MovieName1 and so on.

**For example:**
DTO.MovieID1 will be storing 2 (as "John Wick" is in MovieName1).

I don't want to call the database for 5 or more times to get the IDs. So, I thought of using SQL IN operator and since am using EF-LINQ, so did something like this:

```
var movieDetailUpdateDto = _mapper.Map<MovieDetailUpdateDto>(ViewModel);

var customMovieValuesList = typeof(MovieDetailUpdateDto).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains("moviename")).ToList().Select(x => x.GetValue(movieDetailUpdateDto));
```

The above statement is giving me a list of the movie names but am unable to understand for which field the specific name is.

**For example:**
If the value "John Wick", in the list, is for the field MovieName1 or MovieName2 or any other MovieName fields.

So, I think using Dictionary I can be able to store the fieldname and its values. But, not sure how it will work or whether it will work or not?

Secondly, will it be possible to use "customMovieValuesList" in SQL IN operator using LINQ?

Thirdly, how to assign those MovieIDs back to DTO into respective fields using LINQ?

Also, please suggest if the same can be achievable using SQL Joins.

Comment: This comment may not help to answer your question. In my opinion, you should redesign your `TBL_Transact` table as this table contains the *dynamic* column and highly potential to increase in adding columns if there is a new movie needed to be stored. And this will degrade the query performance.

Comment: hmmm ... that's from  bad disigned APIs came from ... What is wrong with new table TransactElements ?

Comment: can you please show us your actual c# code. i failed to undestand the question.

Comment: @YongShun Yes its correct. This series may increase in future. But, its a legacy application and being used by multiple clients already. Currently, this requirement came to me and I have to do it somehow. I am not interested to go for loops and assigning each value at a time calling the db multiple times. So, trying to implement in some other ways. I also thought if SQL may help me on this but not so sure too on that.

Comment: @PouyaHashemi Hi, I cannot post the actual code but the example is same as it is in real code. So, there is a table called TBL_Movies which has a list of movie names with IDs. There is another table called TBL_Transact where there are columns like MovieID1, MovieID2 and so on. These are all integer columns in TBL_Transact which will store the IDs of movies. API need to be created which will be used directly by the clients and they will pass Movie names through ViewModel, which should update TBL_Transact by respective Movie IDs.

E.g. - MovieName1 = John Wick, so MovieID1 should store 2.

Comment: @Selvin Hmm. Its their legacy code. The table design cannot be changed now. I will have to make some way out of this issue.

Comment: perhaps if you perform projection/materialization properly, you can cast the results to an anonymous type or a tuple with multiple fields. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/projection-operations

Comment: @EmreBener Yeah correct. That's what I did. Provided my doings in the answer section of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I kept trying with LINQ to avoid multiple database calls. Finally, its working fine for me. If anyone wants to share some other way outs, would be glad to follow that as well.

May the solution helps someone :)

```
    public async Task<MovieDetailDtoBase?> UpdateMovieValuesAsync(int movieId, MovieDetailUpdateViewModel movieDetailUpdateViewModel) {
    
    var movieDetailUpdateDto = _mapper.map<MovieDetailUpdateDto>(movieDetailUpdateViewModel);
    
    // The below linq query loops through all the properties of the 
    // movieDetailUpdateDto and gets back the property name and its value as 
    // provided in the DTO, filtering out the null values and empty strings,
    // converting into an anonymous list.

    var moviesKeyValuesList = (typeof(movieDetailUpdateDto).GetProperties()
                               .Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("moviename")).ToList()
                               .Select(t => new { FieldName = t.Name, FieldValue = t.GetValue(movieDetailUpdateDto)?.ToString() })
                               .Where(r => r.FieldValue.Trim() != string.Empty && r.FieldValue != null)
                               .ToList()
                               );
    
    }
```

Thanks everyone for your support.

Comment: happy to be of help, I just would recommend using new lines for each method call to make LINQ more readable :)

Comment: @EmreBener Yes, I did the same in my code file. Here, after pasting I saw the indentation went wrong and so I just posted it here in a single line. Let me try to update the answer maintaining multiple lines.  Thanks :)